# How to fix a 'malformed factor'?

Tags: r

I'm not sure at which point it happened, but I ended up with a vector like this:

```
vec <- structure(c(1L,2L, 33L), .Label = c("first", "second"), class = "factor")
```

And when I call `vec` I get:

> Error in as.character.factor(x) : malformed factor

I would like to "rescue" this vector, for example by substituting `NA` to `33L`, but cannot even do something like `as.character(vec)`. How do I fix it?

Comment: Just remove `33L` and it should work

Comment: What R version are you using? I'm not getting any error in v 3.2.5 and it just represented as `NA`

Comment: @DavidArenburg In 3.3.2 I get error

Comment: @DavidArenburg `R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vec <- structure(c(1L,2L, 33L), .Label = c("first", "second"), class = "factor")

levels(vec) <- levels(vec)

print(vec)
#[1] first  second <NA>  
#Levels: first second
```

You should investigate why you have a malformed factor and fix that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll certainly do that but for now I just needed a quick fix to run a script

Comment: Just in case it is helpful: I got this error when I mistakenly had duplicate column names and did a melt...

Comment: @PeterVermont this is exactly what happened to me, thanks for the tip.